# hashmap on Buffer objects appears to be wrong, why

Tags: javascript

There are two different Buffer objects (different values) in a JavaScript,  but in JavaScript object, they are treated as being equal.  Any idea why? How to force them to be different keys for a JavaScript?  Thanks

my node.js version is 10.15.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
var buf1 = Buffer.from([
    10,
    33,
    45,
    77,
    10,
    33,
    46,
    166,
    140,
    190,
    5,
    241
  ]);
var buf2 = new Buffer.from([
    10,
    33,
    45,
    77,
    10,
    33,
    46,
    168,
    215,
    216,
    5,
    241
]);
let a = {};
a[buf2] = "jon";
console.log(a[buf1]);  //output  jon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a[buf2]` is equivalent to `a[buf2.toString()]`, which is equivalent to `a[buf2.toString('utf-8')]`, which is the cause of your problem: your buffers don't hold valid UTF-8 data, so when converting to an UTF-8 string, invalid code points are replaced by the Unicode replacement character, U+FFFD (encoded as 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD in UTF-8).

To show this, you can run the following code:

```
console.log('buf1', Buffer.from(buf1.toString()).toString('hex'));
console.log('buf2', Buffer.from(buf2.toString()).toString('hex'));
```

The result is the hexadecimal representation of each buffer as it's used as a property "name" (replacement character highlighted):

```
buf1 0a212d4d0a212eefbfbdefbfbdefbfbd05efbfbd
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^
buf2 0a212d4d0a212eefbfbdefbfbdefbfbd05efbfbd
```

As you can see, they are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks so much @robertklep, your answer is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

`a[buf2] = "jon";` is exactly the same as `a['[object: Object]'] = "jon";`, because key of object must be a `string`, if it's not `string` it will be converted to string using `toString` method.

What you wanted to do is:

```
var buf1 = Buffer.from([
    10,
    33,
    45,
    77,
    10,
    33,
    46,
    166,
    140,
    190,
    5,
    241
  ]);
var buf2 = new Buffer.from([
    10,
    33,
    45,
    77,
    10,
    33,
    46,
    168,
    215,
    216,
    5,
    241
]);
let a = {};
a['buf2'] = "jon";
console.log(a[buf1]);  //outputs undefined
console.log(a['buf2']); // outputs "jon"
```